# PXE kickstart install of CentOS 8 wants files that don't exist on DVD

Tags: pxe-boot, kickstart, centos8

I'm trying to use the CentOS-8-x86_64-1905-dvd1.iso as the http source for my PXE/kickstart install.

I'm struggling to understand why the installer is looking of squashfs.img and a directory named LiveOS, neither of which exist in the above iso image.

Should I be using the CentOS-8-x86_64-1905-boot.iso instead? I followed https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/advanced-install/assembly_preparing-for-a-network-install but there was no mention made of which iso to use.

Comment: https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/advanced-install/assembly_creating-installation-sources-for-kickstart-installations/ does not do us any favors. It says to use " cp -r" to copy the contents of the ISO to disk. cp -r will _not_ copy some critical dot files. For example, .treeinfo (in the root of the ISO)will not be copied, and without this file the install will fail.

Answer (score 2):

If you've gotten that message, then you are probably attempting to install CentOS 8 with a CentOS 7 initrd.img and vmlinuz. You have to change the initrd.img and vmlinuz that you point to in your APPEND and KERNEL line in your tftpboot file. Here's an example of a working file.

```
default menu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 30
MENU TITLE PXE Boot install for my server
LABEL Centos 8.2
  MENU LABEL Install Centos 8.2 via Kickstart
  KERNEL /images/CentOS-8.2.2004/vmlinuz
  APPEND initrd=/images/CentOS-8.2.2004/initrd.img ks=ftp://ftp.server.org/pub/kickstart_file_name.cfg
```

This page will tell you where to find those files in your CentOS 8 iso:

https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/advanced-install/assembly_preparing-for-a-network-install/

Answer (score -2):

The CentOS document https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/advanced-install/assembly_creating-installation-sources-for-kickstart-installations/ is wrong. You are better off using rsync to copy the ISO's contents. See my comment above for details.

Comment: Please provide the whole answer and not reference comments on the question. Be sure to include succinct steps that other can follow. E.g. `rsync /mnt/cdrom /data/export/`

Comment: You forgot -av .

Comment: What works reliably is to mount the ISO on a directory that is shared on the network i.e. /var/www/html/{somedir}. I suppose we will eventually set up a local yum mirror.